# devise_invitable: Only allow admin to invite users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, devise-invitable

I am using [`devise_invitable`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) gem to enable invites in my app along with devise for a rails 3 app. I have a `User` & `Profile` model. In `User`,  there is a `role` column which gives type of user.

Now, I would like to restrict feature of creating new invites *only* to admin by scoping this scoping route to `devise/invitations#new` where `user.role=='admin'` & open rest of the routes to everybody. something like this

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations, :invitations]

as :user do
 get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
  put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', as: 'user_registration'

# manually define alll devise_invitable routes, except devise/invitations#new

# accept_user_invitation GET /users/invitation/accept(.:format) devise/invitations#edit

# user_invitation POST /users/invitation(.:format) devise/invitations#create

# also the #accept route goes here

end



resource :profile, except: :destroy

authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.role == "admin"} do

resources :user, controller: "user"

#only allow admin to invite other users

# new_user_invitation GET /users/invitation/new(.:format) devise/invitations#new

end

root to: 'profiles#show'

end
```

Possible? Also, what the the better ways to do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about leaving the standard routes alone and using a **before_filter** in the Invitations controller to check for admin status only for the new and create actions?

```
class Devise::InvitationsController < DeviseController
    ...
    before_filter :is_admin?, :only => [:new, :create]
    ...
end
```

It looks like the devise_invitable gem actually uses this method internally as well:

```
class Devise::InvitationsController < DeviseController
    before_filter :authenticate_inviter!, :only => [:new, :create]
    before_filter :has_invitations_left?, :only => [:create]
    before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:edit, :update]
    ...
end
```

According to their [Readme](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-controllers):

> To change the controller’s behavior, **create a controller that inherits from Devise::InvitationsController**. The available methods are: new, create, edit, and update. You should read the [original controllers source](https://raw.github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/master/app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb) before editing any of these actions.

I would just copy their default controller and try adding my own custom is_admin? before_filter in there for the new and create actions. Of course you'll also have to define the is_admin? method that the before filter calls.

Comment: I was looking to do this directly from routes but I guess, I will have to work this way. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 7):

One simple way is just overwrite the **authenticate_inviter!** method in side of **ApplicationController** as follow:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  private
  def authenticate_inviter!
    unless user.role=='admin'
      redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Access Denied"
    end
    super
  end
  ...
end
```

And include DeviseInvitable::Inviter module into your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include DeviseInvitable::Inviter
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This approach is (now) recommended in the [devise_invitable readme](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable). See the "Controller filter" section.

Comment: I like this example, but I think the Inviter module does not need to be included if you're using the the `devise` method in your model.

Comment: I would suggest two changes: (1) "and return" need to be added after redirect_to method otherwise it can throw DoubleRenderError. (2) better check if user logged in otherwise if guest try hit this path it can cause undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass.